# Dummy backend for ISO 8583 message

Tags: iso, iso8583

I want to create dummy backend for ISO 8583 messages. The necessary condition for this problem is "to run the jPos/other ATM test-suite against this backend".

Comment: So, what's your problem?

Comment: I want to know the possible methods for doing this task

Comment: Did you do any investigation?

Comment: I did but not able to get any proper direction . Like i got this site and a blog, link: http://j8583.sourceforge.net/index.html and http://paparadit.blogspot.in/2012_07_01_archive.html .

Comment: Can anyone provide me some sort of implementation methodology for doing this task.?

Comment: I assume there is some sort of "dummy" ISO 8583 server emulators. from this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22362501/how-should-jpos-be-configured-used-in-a-prod-environment?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

You may try simple [jReactive-iso8583 server](https://github.com/kpavlov/jreactive-8583).

Have a look at [client-server integration test](https://github.com/kpavlov/jreactive-8583/blob/master/src/test/java/org/jreactive/iso8583/example/ClientServerIT.java).

Usage example:

Spring config:

```
@Configuration
public class Iso8583ServerConfig {

    @Value("${iso8583.connection.port}")
    int port;

    @Bean
    public org.jreactive.iso8583.server.Iso8583Server iso8583Server() throws IOException {
        return new org.jreactive.iso8583.server.Iso8583Server(port, serverMessageFactory());
    }

    @Bean
    MessageFactory serverMessageFactory() throws IOException {
        MessageFactory messageFactory = ConfigParser.createDefault();
        messageFactory.setCharacterEncoding(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII.name());
        messageFactory.setUseBinaryMessages(false);
        messageFactory.setAssignDate(true);
        return messageFactory;
    }
```

}

Add custom message listener somewhere:

```
server.addMessageListener(new IsoMessageListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean applies(IsoMessage isoMessage) {
            return isoMessage.getType() ==  0x200;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMessage(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, IsoMessage isoMessage) {
            capturedRequest = isoMessage;
            final IsoMessage response = server.getIsoMessageFactory().createResponse(isoMessage);
            response.setField(39, IsoType.ALPHA.value("00", 2));
            response.setField(60, IsoType.LLLVAR.value("XXX", 3));
            ctx.writeAndFlush(response);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Then run a server:

```
 server.init();
 server.start();
```

Shutdown server:

```
 server.shutdown();
```